# How could I mimic C's CHAR type in Node?

Tags: c, node.js

I'm not very familiar with `C`, but I have an app I'm trying to convert over to `Node (JS)`.

I think `char` may be relatable to Nodes `new Buffer()` but I'm not 100% certain on this. Any information would be great thanks.

I have this bit of code here:

```
char data[80];
unsigned long long flag=0;

mysql_real_escape_string(&mysql,data,(char*)&flag,sizeof(flag));
```

Which `mysql_real_escape_string` should just copy the data from `(char*)&flag)` into `data`.

I'm wondering if I could do this like

```
var flag = 123;
var buf = new Buffer(80)
buf.writeUInt32LE(flag);
```

if I `console.log(buf);` I get

```
buf.toString();
'\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000��p\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000P��\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000x��\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@��_�\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000'
```

if I `printf("%s", data);` I get

```
\0@\0\0\0\0\0
```

Any information would be great thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use something like [`mysql2`](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) for database connectivity?

Comment: @mscdex I'm using [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) but it looks like they store `data` in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why you are allocating such a large buffer for such a small bit of data, but creating a `Buffer` in Node does not initialize the underlying memory. Therefore, apart from the first 4 bytes overwritten by `writeUInt32LE` the rest will be gibberish. You should use `fill` to get consistent output.

```
var flag = 123;
var buf = new Buffer(80)
buf.fill(0);
buf.writeUInt32LE(flag);
```

When I add `console.log(buf)`, I get a much more predictable output:

```
<Buffer 7b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >
```

I can't can't compare your output from the C snippet, as it seems your input values don't match. Based on your description, I think this will correct your output.